# Can I know about Microsoft Teams channel member change events?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-teams

I am developing an external app of Microsoft Teams.

I want to synchronize "channel members of my external app" with "channel members of Teams".

So I want to know modifies of channel members of Teams as follows:

1. Someone has created a Teams channel.
2. Some members have joined the Teams channel.
3. Some members have left the Teams channel.

I understand I have a Webhook and an Office 365 Connector, but I can only receive chat events.

I also understand that the Microsoft Graph API can be used to know channel information.
However, this doesn't help up to know the change events for Microsoft Teams channel members.

Comment: In order to get the events (member added/member removed...) you need to subscriber to the channels. Please check this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/subscribe-to-conversation-events?tabs=dotnet) for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Graph only supports change notifications (webhooks) and change tracking (delta) on chatMessages today (or channel messages).
Because a team is a group, you can also track changes/get notified of people joining/leaving the Team (by tracking/subscribing to the members of the group), but not the channel itself.
As Abhijit mentioned, you could leverage the bot SDK to track members joining and leaving a channel, but that's outside of Microsoft Graph's APIs at the moment.

If you'd like to have support for channel members delta/webhooks you can ask for it on [uservoice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com).